# Stripe subscription links that end after a number of payments

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using the Stripe dashboard to create a subscription product link. This will be a simple web link - I am not using a server or the Stripe API.  I want the subscription to be monthly, but end automatically after 6 months and stop charging the customer.

I see in the Stripe API documentation this can be accomplished with Phases and Iterations and setting end_behavior=cancel.  But I don't see how to do this with Payment Links - there is only the option to add name/value metadata fields for the payment link.

Is it possible to have a Stripe Subscription link that ends after a number of iterations without having to use the server API or webhooks (just using the dashboard)?